# Web API and moving DTO from same project to another solution

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am having an issue with a few web api calls after I have tried to move the dto classes from the same project to a class library in another solution. After the move, they always end up with null value.

The only change I made was creating a set of new cs files in the other solution and copy the classes over to those files and then remove the original DTO files.

The html code, the web api classes (except a new reference to the class project containing the DTOs) haven't been changed, and if I insert the original DTO files, they methods work fine again.

Anyone have some ideas I can explore.

Comment: other solution? you mean other project inside the same solution?

Comment: I use a set of solutions, and then reference the dlls from one to another. Each solution contains a series of projects. So in this case, I have moved the cs files from one project in a solution to another project in another solution.

Comment: How do you add reference to the class library from different solution?

Comment: I did a reference of the release dll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found the answer to my problem.

I inserted a simple:

```
var modelstate = ModelState;
```

and placed a break point on it, which pointed me in the direction of an incompatible dll version of another dll that both projects were referencing.